# Nativescript Collapsed GridLayout Row still take place in the UI

Tags: nativescript

Using this Layout:

```
<GridLayout columns="70, *" rows="auto, auto, auto">

    <Label row="0" col="0" rowSpan="3" text="A" style="background-color: red;"></Label>

    <Label row="0" col="1" text="B" style="background-color: green;"></Label>
    <Label row="1" col="1" text="C" visibility="collapse" style="background-color: blue;"></Label>
    <Label row="2" col="1" text="D" style="background-color: orange"></Label>

</GridLayout>
```

Is there a reason I can see a white space between row B and D ? I expected row D to go up and take the place of row C.

I'm testing on a physical device so here's a quick paint of the result:
[image]

I expected the result to behave like this html table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" style="width: 70px; background-color: red;">A</td>
            <td style="width: 500px; background-color: green;">B</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="display: none; background-color: blue;">C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: orange;">D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a snip of the html result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have defined a GridLayout with 3 rows and you set the label D to the third row. Even when the label C is collapsed, its place won't be taken up.

If you would like to have a layout exactly as the second picture, then I suggest this:

```
<GridLayout columns="70, *" rows="auto">
    <Label row="0" col="0" text="A" style="background-color: red;"></Label>
    <StackLayout row="0" col="1">
        <Label text="B" style="background-color: green;"></Label>
        <Label text="C" visibility="collapse" style="background-color: blue;"></Label>
        <Label text="D" style="background-color: orange"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

P/s: if you put the label C back to visible, the layout will resize itself also

Comment: Make sense... I forgot that since it is defined in the GridLayout itself, it'll stick to 3 rows no matter what. I'll go for a StackLayout as you suggested, thanks!